# Looking to get P4PORT from p4api.net

Tags: perforce, p4api.net

It seems the call is Connection.GetP4EnvironmentVar( "P4PORT" ), but to be able to interrogate a connection I need to connect to a server and hence need a P4PORT in advance, and so have a chicken and egg situation. What is the best practice in this situation? Look in "HKCU\SOFTWARE\perforce\environment" ?

The goal is to run a C# app that can read the P4 env variables to grab P4PORT.

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0):

Per [the spec fetcher example](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4api.net/Content/P4API_NET/example-console-spec-fetcher-app.html#Example_console_specification_fetcher_application) in the doc, you can create a `ServerAddress` with an empty URI -- this isn't explicitly explained in the doc, but that must be how to have your app get P4PORT from the environment.  Assuming that the logic to pull `P4PORT` from the environment lives in `ServerAddress`, you might be able to do something like:

```
string p4Port = ServerAddress("").Uri;
```

If not, then it might need to be a more convoluted incantation along the lines of:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerAddress(""));
string p4Port = server.Address.Uri;
```

or even:

```
Repository rep = new Repository(new Server(new ServerAddress("")));
string p4Port = rep.Connection.GetP4EnvironmentVar("P4PORT");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these work. If the server address is constructed with a blank address, then server.Address.Uri is also blank.

However, if we do a rep.Connection.Connect( null ); then the field is populated (albeit after a timeout)

Thanks!